# HP G60-530US Wi-Fi disables on boot or resume

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

My HP G60-530US laptop worked fine for both Windows and Ubuntu 10.04 until one day when the Wi-Fi was disabled by the hardware.

For some reason, Ubuntu has stopped enabling the Wi-Fi in response to the button for that, which wouldn't be so bad if I could just reboot into Windows, enable the Wi-Fi, and switch back.  Sadly, the Wi-Fi disables itself when I turn on the computer or resume it from standby, which combines with my lack of control in Ubuntu to produce the undesirable result of having to use Windows or connect through Ethernet.

Is this a correctable BIOS problem from HP, an uncorrectable BIOS problem from HP, or just an Ubuntu problem?

If I can fix it, then how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have no idea what caused this problem, but I seem to have accidentally done something right.  I no longer have this problem.  Maybe it's because I accidentally re-enabled HP Wireless Assistant under Windows, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have an HP G60-635DX. The SAME EXACT thing happened to me.

While I dont know how or why this happens, I know how to get around it.

Under Ubuntu, open Terminal and enter:

```
     sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Im not sure exactly how it works, but this enables WIFI under Ubuntu, and should work on many Linux distribs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just press the WiFi button and check that the status of the WiFi is "wireless button networks disabled". Then suspend Ubuntu.

Now enter your password and log in. Check your WiFi status. It will be switched on.

This works on Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10, 11.04, 11.10, …

Answer (score 0):

What if the WiFi has disabled itself, and you have only Linux installed -- how to unblock it? It turns out not to be straightforward on some modern Linux installations (perhaps, because of strange interaction between 2 modules, or because the device might interpret some incoming tumbler signals wrong). I try to enumerate the suggested solutions I've found ([my experiences in Russian](http://www.altlinux.org/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA:IvanZakharyaschev/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%9B.#WiFi)):

1. *First*, do `rmmod -f ath5k`, and then `rfkill unblock all`;
2. Use the special parameter of `ath5k` module to ignore the hardware block (because the WiFi-device might receive wrong signals from the button, for example, if the firmware doesn't correspod to way it has been connected, and so on).
3. Suppress the loading of hp-wmi (BTW, what's the purpose of this module? `modinfo` says: HP laptop WMI hotkeys driver; "[The entry for hp-wifi is for the software that monitors the switch.](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/wireless/481537-wireless-trouble-opensuse-12-2-hp-notebook.html#post2511765)"):

   - "[Workaround #2: Add hp-wmi to modprobe blacklist.  Again, this causes only phy0 wireless to be reported and phy0 always accurately reflects the state of the hardware (both soft and hard blocked).](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2012/10/msg00145.html)"
   - "[Instead of removing my ath9k and adding it back, I simply removed the hp-wifi module like so. rmmod hp-wmi (do this, this removes the hp-wifi module which you don't need now )](http://www.debianuserforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2683)"